# No namenode to start while setting single node hadoop

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, namenode

I am trying to set up a single node cluster in hadoop, but after giving the command **start-all.sh** , jps doesn't show namenode and when I stop all processes, I get the result as no namenode to stop. Also, I saw at few places that clearing the tmp folder data solves the problem, but I am not able to find it in my hadoop folder. Following is the result of **jps** command:

```
root@neel:~/sbin# jps
4166 ResourceManager
4793 Jps
4299 NodeManager
3995 SecondaryNameNode
3804 DataNode
27852 -- process information unavailable
root@neel:~/sbin#
```

Comment: Go to the `/var/log/hadoop` (or where ever your logs are). Inside there you will find a log file for `NameNode`. Post that log content here. It is hard to say what is issue with just `jps` showing no `NameNode` daemon.

Answer (score 0):

```
1 Clear the namenode and datanode folder 
2 format the namnode and datanode
   $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop namenode -format
   $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs namenode -format
   $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop datanode -format
   $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs datanode -format
3 Then start hadoop
```

Comment: 5042 Main
31077 ResourceManager
31210 NodeManager
30906 SecondaryNameNode
31532 Jps
30718 DataNode
I get the following output from jps command. Still the namenode has not been started.

Comment: have you clear your namenode folder?
after clearing  please stop and start hadoop